# Android: How to control placement of bottom app bar actions?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-bottomappbar

I am implementing [material design bottom app bar](https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom/#specs) but I can't get the placement of the icons as I want.

[image]
This is what my app bar looks like currenly.

[image]
This is how I want it to look.

I want to have control over which side the actions is placed. Is that possible?

Comment: This might help you [Bottom app bar problem with placing icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767397/bottom-app-bar-problem-with-placing-icons)

Comment: I saw that one but I would like to know if there is such a think implemented in the bottom app bar.